# How to update Mysql query with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, sql-update

I have a field LastScanDate (varchar) and I need it to update ScanDate (DateTime).
The subquery t2 works fine when I run it separately.

But when I try to use it to update Scandate, I get the error '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT(yr,"-",m,"-",d," ", h,":",mit) as recdate from (Select y' at line 6"

```
UPDATE test as t1

set t1.ScanDate = recdate

(
SELECT 

CONCAT(yr,"-",m,"-",d," ", h,":",mit) as recdate

from 
(Select
year(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")) AS yr,
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")) AS m, 
Day(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")) AS d,
Hour(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")) AS h,
Minute(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")) AS mit,
ID,
ScanDate
FROM test
WHERE ScanDate IS NULL
) as t2
)
where t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query really makes it look like you want to update values in the same table and on the same row.

If so, and assuming that your string really is a date a format that corresponds to the one you specify, you can just do:

```
update test
set scandate = str_to_date(lastscandate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')
where scandate is null
```

Comment: This solution did work but as I was using concat as you can not insert date format "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i" into a DateTime field as DateTime must be %Y-%m-%d %H:%i. but I modified the set statement to be the concat statement and it worked. I will post the code that worked.

Comment: @Eric_DB: I think you misunderstand the purpose of `str_to_date()`. What it does is convert a string to a `date`, which is exactly what you need here. The second argument specifies the format of the input string. See the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

this code is what worked;

```
update test
set ScanDate =

CONCAT
(year(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")),
"-",
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")),
"-",
Day(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i")),
" ",
if (right(LastScanDate,2) = "PM", Hour(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i"))+12,Hour(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i"))),
":",
Minute(STR_TO_DATE(`LastScanDate`, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%i"))
)

where ScanDate is null
```